# Geometry node - Rotating instance along a curve with animation

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

I move objets along a curve. I use the *Sample Curve* node, which is OK for the move but not for rotation.
When I use the *Curves to Point* node with outputs *Normal* and *Rotation* it's Ok for rotation.

How can I have the output rotation or equivalent with the *Sample Curve* node?

[image]

[image: Geometry node]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your concrete case, you would also have to transform the tangents of the curve, together with the normals, into a rotation.

Just add another node `Align Euler to Vector` in between.

[image]

Tip: You can also create an endless loop of the animation with the node `Scene Time` and the math node `Fraction`.

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2)*</sub>

Comment: Thx a lot, it's exatly this.