# Traffic along a curve in Geo Nodes without clipping (overlapping)

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes, instances, random

I made a traffic system with Geometry Nodes as you can see below. (Thanks to the [How to make Traffic Systems in Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqTXiw6MJgI) video by Bbbn19 on YouTube)

The problem is that clipping occurs and that I can't find a way to set a minimum distance in between the points/ cars.

I have seen a suggestion to use the *Distribute Points on Face* node and the *Poisson Disk* function within it, but I'm not able to make it work.

Another person on Youtube suggested:

> If you use integers instead of floats with the random number generation and then multiply the numbers appropriately you should be able to give the cars a minimum spacing. I think that should be a simple solution.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd use a 1D voronoi texture, check for distance to the center of 2nd cell and see if it's not too small, and go from there...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your concrete case, you would only have to define a minimum distance between the individual points.

To do this, simply add the math node `Snap` after the node `Random Value` and define the distance there.

[image]

There would be still another possibility:

[image]

Here I create random values, at between a minimum distance and maximum distance. I accumulate these values with `Accumulate Field` and thus generate the required sample points.

---

If you also want to animate the cars, you might be interested in the following answer:
[Geometry node - Rotating instance along a curve with animation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/270820/145249)

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot for that already Quellenform! :-)

About your second solution:

I would like to be able to determine the maximum number of the **random value** node by the **curve length** node and that doesn't seem to be possible here.

When I change the 'count' in the **curve to points** node, this changes the total length of the traffic jam.

When I change the 'min distance' value in the **Random Value** node: this also changes the total length of the traffic jam.

Is there a way by any chance to avoid the double points in your first solution as a possible solution to these issues?

Comment: @PieterLeon Yes, of course, you can do that too. I have just updated the answer.

Comment: Hah, that's awesome! You made my day again Stephan. :-) A coffee is coming your way!

Comment: @PieterLeon Thank you for your support! That makes helping twice as much fun!