# Traffic animation with cars along a curve

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

I would like to take [this earlier question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/275984/traffic-along-a-curve-in-geo-nodes-without-clipping-overlapping) a step further by animating the traffic line.

I've added nodes to the NodeTree to achieve this animation, as shown in the attached image.

[image: nodetree animated traffic]
[image: what the animation looks like]

While the traffic line moves, I've encountered two challenges:

- When I use a collection of cars, the instances (cars) constantly change on the spot
- The animation sequence occasionally exhibits a slight 'jump'. It's not a smooth, seamless loop.

To illustrate the issue, I've created a [video on YouTube](https://youtu.be/W8gFEOY-Mmc)
The Blender file is in attachment.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem arises in this case because after moving the points you merge them again with `Merge by Distance`. This also changes the indices, which leads to this erratic behavior during instantiation.

However, by capturing the index with `Capture Attribute` before merging the points and using this as *Instance Index*, you stabilize the indices and the erratic behaviour disappears:

[image]

Comment: That works! Thanks! :-)
I timed that about every 10 seconds the points on the curve seem to be redistributed/ a jump of some sort occurs.
Do you know where this comes from?

Comment: @PieterLéon The jump that occurs every ~10 seconds is due to the fact that this setup is time-based and is controlled by the *Scene Time* node. Since the number of defined frames of your timeline is limited to 250 frames, your counter starts again at 0 after 10.416 seconds (250 Frames/24fps), which causes the jump. In this case, you would therefore have to increase the end frames (frame range) accordingly.

Comment: Ah, it's that simple. I clearly don't know much about animation. Thanks again Stephan! :-) A coffee is coming your way. And best wishes for the new year!