Simulating points moving along curves
I'm trying to create a system of points moving along curves.
In the first step, a single curve is duplicated into a track of 6 parallel curves with these geometry nodes:

Then I'm using the simulation zone to move the points:

But I can't get it to work the way I want it to. My best attempt looks like it creates new points along the curves instead of creating them at the beginning and moving them.



While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

By "points moving along curves" do you mean something like this? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/270820/145249

@quellenform No, that is simple. I mean spawning them at the beginning and then moving them along.

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos How am I supposed to add clarity when I don't know what it is that people might not understand? If somebody had a specific request for more details, I would be happy to clarify it. Who does it help to just close the question? Do you realize that people go to this forum because they need help?

Hi @Lynx095, simply mentioning "system of points moving along curves" doesn't provide enough context for the community to offer meaningful assistance. It would be really helpful if you could share additional details or screenshots to clarify what you're referring to. Like screenshot of what is happening versus what you are expecting for example. Once you provide more information, we can get the conversation reopened. And as Duarte has mentioned don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file.

@HarryMcKenzie I chose to share my file instead of a screenshot because the problem I have is in the movement. A good result and a bad result would look identical on a still image.

Your file was initially inaccessible, we encourage using blend-exchange.com instead. Other than that, the problem with sharing a file is that someone unwilling or unable to download cannot understand your question.  Same for some on mobile or unable to open your file. When it is eventually removed, your question becomes incomprehensible for future visitors.
For motion demonstrations share GIFs See https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449

(Using Blender 4.2.1)


Approach based on the Factor

Dark blue nodes: One point every frame is added to the Geometry recycled by the Simulation zone. Two attributes are attached to this point. fac is its normalized curvilinear abscissa along a Spline ; it is initialized at 0.
spline is the index of the Spline this point will travel ; it is drawn randomly.
Dark pink nodes: From its fac and spline attributes, the Position of a point is computed using a Sample Curve node, then it is updated using a Set Position node.
Dark green nodes: The fac abscissa is incremented and stored.
Dark red nodes: Points reaching the end of their spline, i.e. those whose fac abscissa is higher than 1, are deleted.
Resources:
(Blender 4.2.1+)

Approach based on the Length

Using Length instead of Factor to sample the curve requires to base the deletion selection mask on the Spline Length node.
Resources:
(Blender 4.2.1+)

Thank you, it works really well, except for the next step of the project I need it to be based on curve length, not factor. I've already changed it to use length instead but now the nodes that delete the points which reach the end are not working properly. Specifically I have a problem finding the proper length per curve to use for the compare node.

Side note: beware that the length of the curve (a collection of splines) and the length of each spline are not the same property.

solved it, thanks.
